# Subtracting pointers why is 4227140 - 4227136 = 1?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

[This](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8) document says the following about pointers to cells in an array:

> if the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the
> expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N (where N has the
> value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and i-n-th elements of the
> array object, provided they exist.

I have an array that is declared this way:

```
static int heap [MANY];
```

I output the pointer to heap:

```
printf("heap = %ld\n", heap);
```

The output showed this:

```
heap = 4227136
```

So that is the pointer to `heap[0]`, right?

Next, I output the pointer to `heap[1]`:

```
printf("heap + 1 = %ld\n", (heap+1));
```

I expected, based on the quote above, that the pointer would have a value `1` more than `4227136`, i.e., I expected the pointer would have the value `4227137`. I was surprised when I saw that the pointer is `4` more than `4227136`:

```
heap + 1 = 4227140
```

Why is the pointer to `heap[1]` `4` more than the pointer to `heap[0]`?

Then I tried subtracting pointers: I subtracted `heap[0]` from `heap[1]`:

```
printf("(heap+1) - heap = %d\n", ((heap+1)-heap));
```

I expected the output to be: `4227140 - 4227136 = 4`

Instead I got an answer of `1`:

```
(heap+1) - heap = 1
```

I am confused. Why am I getting these results?

Comment: Pointer addition/subtraction is in granuality of the `sizeof` of the corresponding type.

Comment: `I expected, based on the quote above, that the pointer would have a value 1 more than 4227136` _Why?_ It specifically says `point to, respectively, the i+n-th and i-n-th elements of the array object`. The `i + 1'th` element isn't at address `i + 1` but at `i + sizeof(int)`.

Comment: If you want integer math, use _integers_.  Treating pointers as integers has pitfalls.  Pointer addition/subtraction is just one of many such holes.  It is also UB to do `printf("heap = %ld\n", heap);`.  Pointers are not integers are not pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `sizeof (int)` is 4 bytes on your machine. `heap+1` points to the next element. Not byte.

The operator `[]` is simple syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic. `a[1]` is the same as `*(a+1)`. This have the funny consequence that `a[1]` is the same as `1[a]`.

Answer (score 3):

Complete (i.e. non-`void`) pointers are incremented based on the size of the pointed to type.

Think about this, if `sizeof(int) == 4` on your system and you have a pointer to an `int` array, like, `int data[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; int *p = data;` what would you expect to dereference with `*(p + 1)`? The element `sizeof(int)` bytes up, not the next byte up.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account your quote then `&heap[0]` or `heap + 0` points to the first element of the array while `&heap[1]` or `heap + 1` points to the second element of the array.

So `( heap + 1 ) - ( heap + 0 )` is equal to `1`. That is the difference of two pointers that point to elements of the same array is equal to the number (positive or negative) of elements between the pointers.

On the other hand, as `heap + 1` points to the second element of the array then the stored address in the pointer differs from the address of the first element of the array by the value `sizeof( heap[0] )` or that is the same by the value `sizeof( int )` that in your case is equal to `4`.